# How to using a customize namespace?

Tags: c#, namespaces

this is my project tree:

```
.
├── Human.cs
└── main.cs
```

this is my main.cs:

```
using Human;
namespace HelloWorldApplication
{
   class HelloWorld
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      { 
         Human.Man.sayHi();
      }
   }
}
```

this is my Human.cs:

```
using System;
namespace Human
{
    class Man{
        public static void sayHi(){
            Console.WriteLine("man is saying 'hi'");
        }
    }
}
```

I want to use Human in my main.cs. The doc of MSDN that I have found does not show how to import custom namespace.

when I try to compile main.cs, it throws `main.cs(2,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name`Human' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?`

Comment: Add `using Human;` just below `using System;` There are other ways to do it but that is by far the most common.

Comment: @JohnWu Do you mean Human.cs? I just try it but does not work.

Comment: No I mean `Human` That is the name of your namespace. The name of the .cs file is irrelevant-- it it automatically included as long as it is in the same project.

Comment: You don't need `using Human` since you're supplying the namespace in the following line (it doesn't hurt to have the using): `Human.Man.sayHi();`. With the using, you could simply write `Man.sayHi();`. Either way, your code works fine.

Comment: I've added your code to a test project and uploaded it [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aX-Nhbh76UpsyLwv-AUrXQGily7xR-aT/view?usp=sharing). I'll delete this link later since it won't be in my Google Drive forever.

Comment: @john thanks, I have downloaded it.